# Can I have revisions for submissions?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am interested in using webform submissions as a data capture method versus creating new content types for each set of fields - I think it adds great flexibility and capabilities to tailor without having to mess with content types.

But ... what I can not do/figure out is version control on a webform submission.  In my use case a single data entry will start and then as a function of time (over like 1 year) be updated.  I want to track revision history like I can do with content types - is that a possibility?

Comment: Have you had a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/config_entity_revisions yet? `The module was initially developed to provide revisions and moderation for Webforms.` Do you really mean Webforms, or do you mean Webform submissions?

Comment: Thanks leymannx - yeah I was looking for the webform submissions - thanks for the engagement!